# cmake pre-build command to copy files from external repository

Tags: cmake, build, build-system

In my project, I have an external dependency (a Github repository) from which I want to copy certain files to the source and include directories of my project. I only need a subset of the source and header files in the external repository, so I just want to be able to copy the updated versions of the files I need into the relevant directories in my project. I believe `ExternalProject_Add` should be the right command to download the files from an external project but I can't figure out how to copy them to my source and include directories before each build. Is there an option of `ExternalProject_Add` to achieve this, or should a custom build rule be added using `add_custom_command` which copies the files after the external project is downloaded?

Comment: Why would you _copy_ the files? Did you review the examples section in documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#examples ?

Comment: The external repository contains multiple targets that build a library and multiple executables. I'm only interested in using the library in my project and I don't need the source files for the application from which the executables are built. Therefore, I don't want to use the `CMakeLists.txt` file that is included in the external repo.  I reviewed the examples you linked but couldn't make much sense of the for my use case. Cmake newbie here, I might be misunderstanding some concept.

Comment: `I'm only interested in using the library in my project and I don't need the source files for the application` So you want to _install_ the library? It's called installing - ex. you download firefox, not firefox sources. But if the library is not _packaged_, then you have to recompile it anyway, then just `add_subdirectory` it.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong saying that a library is built; it seems that only two executables are built. You can check the `CMakeLists.txt` of the external repository I want to link to [here](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/scream/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). I need to compile and install the library and don't want to compile the executables. When I do `add-subdirectory`, I guess cmake will use the `CMakeLists.txt` in the subdirectory (here `code`), so I still can't figure it out how to compile a library without modifying the given `CMakeLists.txt` (which is not under my control).

Comment: Great - so add the repository as a git submodule and then create your own CMakeLists.txt with your own configuration for it. Anyway, library is clearly created at https://github.com/EricssonResearch/scream/blob/04a8f18e509be6d594828eac757dcf2d9ac26f67/code/wrapper_lib/CMakeLists.txt#L28

Comment: How about file(DOWNLOAD) command? Check [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ou can check the CMakeLists.txt of the external repository I want to link to here. I need to compile and install the library and don't want to compile the executables

You can add the external code either via `git submodule` if your code is inside a submodule, or by using FetchContent as expalined in the documentation:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
       screamrepo
       GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/EricssonResearch/scream"
)
FetchContent_GetProperties(screamrepo)
if(NOT screamrepo_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(screamrepo)
endif()
# use ${screamrepo_SOURCE_DIR} for source dir
```

If the external code is well structured and exposes the library you want to have, then:

```
add_subdirectory(the/source/path EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

and use the library. If not, like in cases you do not like third party cmake configuration or it comes with unsupported configuration, write your own target `add_library` and configuration and include paths that use the other repository files from source dir.